# Save Image to Google Drive through Python exe

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, image-processing, google-oauth

I am trying to save image through Python on Google Drive (one of the part of my industry project). On normal run -Google Cloud API key (.json format) and image on same folder, it is running flawlessly. But after creating its exe and running (Gentle Remainder added Google Cloud API key (.json format) and image on same folder) its giving error: "googleappiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: drive version: v3 and then [13736] Failed to execute script ' Script_Name' due to unhandled exception!"

Need Help. Thanks

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# Load credentials from your JSON file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'My_Actual_Json_Key', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])

# Create the Drive service
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Specify the parent folder ID where you want to upload the image
parent_folder_id = 'MY_Actual_Parent_Folder_Id'

image_file_path = 'Salzburg3.jpg' # Define the image file to upload
image_file_name = 'Salzburg3.jpg'  # The name you want for the file in Drive

# Create file metadata for the image
file_metadata = {
    'name': image_file_name,
    'parents': [parent_folder_id]  # Specify the parent folder
}
# Upload the image file to the specified folder
media = MediaFileUpload(image_file_path, mimetype='image/jpg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
if file:
    print(f'Image file ID: {file.get("id")}')
else:
    print('Failed to upload the image.')
```

I am unable to understand why its working on normal run  and not running on after creation of exe.

Comment: Have you made sure the file paths are valid?

Comment: Yes Sir. For both cases file paths are valid. My python version is 3.11.3.

Comment: You could make an exe with console and check the logs that come up for more details

Comment: Thanks sir for your replay and looking up for the issue. I have seen this error "googleappiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: drive version: v3 and then [13736] Failed to execute script ' Script_Name' due to unhandled exception!" on  exe's console.